LyX 2.4 dropdown menu values hidden
Example 1. "Maximum last files":

Example 2. "Make auto-save snapshots every":

Expanding the Preferences window doesn't help.
How can I fix this? Or is this a bug?

This is a Qt bug that affects LyX on Windows. It can be worked around by selecting a different Qt theme. It seems that the Qt theme "windows11" is what triggers this issue. See this LyX bug report for more details.

Will such bugs be corrected in the next update? Any idea when that next update will be? Thanks!

It's possible LyX could work around the bug by forcing a Qt theme on the user, but from what I understand the most likely is that Qt releases a fix, and then the next version of LyX (2.4.2) would be built against the Qt that includes that fix. It's possible 2.4.2 will be released the beginning of September (https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=mid&q=9227498c-59c9-14cc-353e-bb14928b9076%40gmail.com) but it is not for sure.
